# How do I delete a level of nodes in a Binary Search Tree in C?

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

Assuming we have the following BST:

```
      5           (level 0)
   3       8      (level 1)
2    4    7    9  (level 2)
```

When trying to delete level 0 or 1 everything is okay but when removing level 2. I get a segmentation fault

```
[1]    18636 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int key;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

// A function to create a new BST node
struct node *newNode(int item)
{
    struct node *temp =  (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->key = item;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

// A function to insert a new node with given key in BST
struct node* insert(struct node* node, int key)
{
    // If the tree is empty, return a new node
    if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

    // Otherwise, recur down the tree
    if (key < node->key)
        node->left  = insert(node->left, key);
    else if (key > node->key)
        node->right = insert(node->right, key);

    // return the (unchanged) node pointer
    return node;
}

// Given a non-empty binary search tree, return the node with minimum
// key value found in that tree. Note that the entire tree does not
// need to be searched.
struct node * minValueNode(struct node* node)
{
    struct node* current = node;

    // loop down to find the leftmost leaf
    while (current->left != NULL)
        current = current->left;

    return current;
}

struct node* deleteNode(struct node* root, int key)
{
    // base case
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
    // then it lies in left subtree
    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key);

    // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
    // then it lies in right subtree
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key);

    // if key is same as root's key, then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
        // node with only one child or no child
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->left;
            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        // node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
        // in the right subtree)
        struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

        // Copy the inorder successor's content to this node
        root->key = temp->key;

        // Delete the inorder successor
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->key);
    }
    return root;
}

void deleteGivenLevel(struct node* root, int level)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (level == 0)
    {
        printf("\n %d will be removed!", root->key);
        root = deleteNode(root, root->key);
    }
    else if (level > 0)
    {
        deleteGivenLevel(root->left, level-1);
        deleteGivenLevel(root->right, level-1);
    }
}

// A function to do inorder traversal of BST
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        printf("\t %d", root->key);
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input, level;
    struct node *root = NULL;

    printf("\nEnter a number to go into the BST: ");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    root = insert(root, input);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter another number (0 to stop): ");
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if (input==0)
        {
            break;
        }
        insert(root, input);
    }

    // print inoder traversal of the BST
    printf("\nBefore Deletion:");
    inorder(root);

    printf("\nWhich level would you like to delete? ");
    scanf("%d",&level);
    deleteGivenLevel(root, level);

    // print inoder traversal of the BST
    printf("\nAfter Deletion:");
    inorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

I've also noticed that it only works when I try to delete level 0 or 1. Other than that it doesn't work. If I add more nodes and I try to delete. It doesn't delete anything at all in that case.

Comment: What is the semantic of `deleteGivenLevel`? To remove all nodes of level `level`?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to delete all nodes of a given level.

Comment: Does your insert work at all? You are ignoring the return value in the while loop. Strange that you dont see errors in printing the tree.

Comment: Yes everything works fine, even when ignoring the return value of the insert there is no difference.

Comment: I haven't actually tested your code, but by inspection I think your deleteGivenLevel calls are storing pointers on the stack (parameter root) that have already been deleted by previous calls to deleteNode. Can you prove this doesn't happen? Or print the memory location before each free and inside your deleteGivenLevel calls as you unwind the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `deleteNode`.

When you call `deleteNode` with a leaf (a node whose `left` and `right` children
are `NULL`) as it's argument, this block is executed:

```
if (root->left == NULL)
{
    struct node *temp = root->right;
    free(root);
    return temp;
}
else if (root->right == NULL)
{
    struct node *temp = root->left;
    free(root);
    return temp;
}
```

The problem here is that you are freeing the leaf but the parent which is
pointing to the leaf does not get updated, thus it keeps pointing to already
freed memory and when you traverse the tree again, then you access invalid
memory. This yields undefined behaviour and it ends in a segfault.

If you go step by step through the `deleteGivenLevel` function, eventually
`root` will be the node with `key == 3`. Then you do

```
deleteGivenLevel(root->left, level-1);
```

where `root->left` is the leaf with `key == 2` and `level-1` is 0. That means
that the in the next call

```
if (level == 0)
{
    printf("\n %d will be removed!", root->key);
    root = deleteNode(root, root->key);
}
```

is executed where `root` is the leaf with `key == 2`. And here is the problem,
that node is removed, but because it is a leave, the node with `key == 3` whose
`left` element points to the leaf, does not get updated.

A quick fix would be to pass the parent node to `deleteNode` and
`deleteGivenLevel` so that you can update the parent node properly. But you
should probably rethink you deleting strategy.

```
struct node* deleteNode(struct node* root, int key, struct node *parent)
{
    // base case
    if (root == NULL) return root;

    // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
    // then it lies in left subtree
    if (key < root->key)
        root->left = deleteNode(root->left, key, NULL); // you could also call
                                                        // with root as the
                                                        // 3rd argument, but
                                                        // you update the parent in this line
                                                        // anyway


    // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
    // then it lies in right subtree
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, key, NULL); // same as above

    // if key is same as root's key, then This is the node
    // to be deleted
    else
    {
        // node with only one child or no child
        if (root->left == NULL)
        {
            struct node *temp = root->right;

            // update only if parent is present
            if(parent)
            {
                if(root->key < parent->key)
                    parent->left = temp;
                else
                    parent->right = temp;
            }

            free(root);
            return temp;
        }
        else if (root->right == NULL)
        {

            struct node *temp = root->left;

            // update only if parent is present
            if(parent)
            {
                if(root->key < parent->key)
                    parent->left = temp;
                else
                    parent->right = temp;
            }

            free(root);
            return temp;
        }

        // node with two children: Get the inorder successor (smallest
        // in the right subtree)
        struct node* temp = minValueNode(root->right);

        // Copy the inorder successor's content to this node
        root->key = temp->key;

        // Delete the inorder successor
        root->right = deleteNode(root->right, temp->key, root);
    }
    return root;
}

void deleteGivenLevel(struct node* root, int level, struct node *parent)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (level == 0)
    {
        printf("\n %d will be removed!", root->key);
        root = deleteNode(root, root->key, parent);
    }
    else if (level > 0)
    {
        deleteGivenLevel(root->left, level-1, root);
        deleteGivenLevel(root->right, level-1, root);
    }
}

void free_tree(struct node *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;

    free_tree(root->left);
    free_tree(root->right);
    free(root);
}
```

Now when you call `deleteGivenLevel` with the real root, `parent` should be set
to `NULL`.

I checked the code with this `main` function, note how `deleteGivenLevel` is
called with `parent == NULL`:

```
int main()
{
    int level;
    struct node *root = NULL;

    int vals[] = { 5, 3, 8, 2, 4, 7, 9 };

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof vals / sizeof *vals; ++i)
        root = insert(root, vals[i]);

    // print inoder traversal of the BST
    printf("\nBefore Deletion:");
    inorder(root);
    puts("");

    level = 2;
    deleteGivenLevel(root, level, NULL);

    // print inoder traversal of the BST
    printf("\nAfter Deletion:");
    inorder(root);
    puts("");

    free_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

and this was the output:

```
$ valgrind ./a 
==24038== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24038== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24038== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24038== Command: ./a
==24038== 

Before Deletion:     2   3   4   5   7   8   9

 2 will be removed!
 4 will be removed!
 7 will be removed!
 9 will be removed!
After Deletion:  3   5   8
==24038== 
==24038== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24038==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24038==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 1,192 bytes allocated
==24038== 
==24038== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24038== 
==24038== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24038== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I also checked the code with more nodes and removing different levels, I didn't
get a single segfault and it seemed to print the correct results anyway.